# Как можно получить список игр всех пользователей discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

есть кусок кода:

```
@commands.command()        
async def gameinfo(self, ctx):
    game_list = []
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        game_list += member.activities
        print(game_list)
```

Выводит он:

```
[<CustomActivity name='test' emoji=None>, <Game name='Visual Studio Code'>]
...
```

Нужно вывести только `Game name`. Но при вызове - `print(game_list['Game name'])`, выдает ошибку:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Если обратиться индексом - `print(game_list[1])`, то:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Суть команды, нужно собрать со всех пользователей в дискорде статус активности (во что они играют) и выдать количество онлайна в определенной игре. Спасибо за любую поомщь!

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы пишите:

```
print(game_list[1])
```

И получаете ошибку:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Это говорит о том, что в списке нет элемента с индексом 1,  список состоит из одного элемента с индексом 0.

Попробуйте так.

```
for member in ctx.guild.members:
        game_list.append(member.activities)
        print(game_list)
```